# Ломается слайдер (Slick + Tabs)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

На первом ТАБе слайдер работает нормально, а на остальных не работает пока не сделаешь скрол влево или вправо, после чего происходит инициализация слайдера и он работает.

```js
$('.tab-content.current').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 5,
  dots: true
});

$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 5,
    dots: true
  });
})
```

```css
.container .row ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 8px;
}

.container .row li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.container .row li.current {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tabs-1">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-2">Tab 2</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-3">Tab 3</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-4">Tab 4</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tabs-5">Tab 5</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content current">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 1</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 2</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 3</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 4</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 5</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 6</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 7</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 8</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 9</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 1, Tab 0</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 1</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 2</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 3</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 4</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 5</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 6</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 7</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 8</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 9</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 2, Tab 0</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-content">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 1</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 2</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 3</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 4</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 5</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 6</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 7</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 8</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 9</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 3, Tab 0</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4" class="tab-content">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 1</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 2</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 3</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 4</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 5</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 6</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 7</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 8</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 9</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 4, Tab 0</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-5" class="tab-content">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 1</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 2</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 3</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 4</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 5</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 6</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 7</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 8</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 9</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/ccc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        <h6>Section 5, Tab 0</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На остальных вкладках слайдеры поломаны т.к. в момент своей инициализации их контейнер имеет `display: none`. Вам необходимо запускать слайдер после того как таб, в котором он находится, становится активным.

Comment: Поправил код, вроде работает норм